# Why is Xpath printed instead of the text inside the element?

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape match statistics of a game of football yesterday at the following url:

https://www.flashscore.com/match/8S0QVm38/#match-statistics;0

I've written code, just for Webdriver to select the stats I want and print them for me so I can then see what I want to use. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/8S0QVm38/#match-statistics;0")
print(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("statText--homeValue"))
```

A list of elements are printed out and to be honest, I don't know if this was what I was looking for because what is returned doesn't show anything to identify with what i'm looking at in the developer tools.

I'm trying to get all the numbers under statistics like Possession and shots on target, but print returns a list of xpaths like this, where the session is the same but the element is always different:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="da88ca87-e318-934e-ba75-dca1d652cd37", element="c53f5f3e-2c89-b34c-a639-ab50fbbf0c33")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="da88ca87-e318-934e-ba75-dca1d652cd37", element="3e422b45-e26d-de44-8994-5f9788462ec4")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="da88ca87-e318-934e-ba75-dca1d652cd37", element="9e110a54-4ecb-fb4b-9d8f-ccd1b210409d")>, <
```

Anyone know why this is and what I can do to get the actual numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting are not XPaths, but a list of WebElement objects. To get text from each try

```
print([node.text for node in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("statText--homeValue")])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have printed the generators instead of actual contents. For that you have to use `.text` for each element. Like,

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("statText--homeValue")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

You can opt for a list comprehensive method shown in [Andersson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126815/3488550) also.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated